# JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSString

Tags: ios, react-native, simulator

I am getting the following error screen sometimes when I reload my React Native app in iOS Simulator.

[image]

Sometimes it doesn't happen at all but sometimes a few times during the day.

I am using SignalR client in my app as well as Firebase Messaging.

I have tried to put a **try catch blocks** to all of my app including where I use AsyncStorage but this is still happening.

Very frustrating.

Answer (score 33):

my problem was with source of the images that i had in my component. i had tell the image components to pass null as source while response of the server for the image was empty or null. means:

```
<Image source={{uri: null}} style={styles.myImageStyle}/>
```

it was ok with android but in ios i ran into this error. so i changed my code to following and it's working fine now.

```
const imageUri = myImageUri!=null ? myImageUri : ""

<Image source={imageUri.length!=0?{uri: imageuri}: null} style={styles.myImageStyle}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. this is a common cause. saved my day.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this when using AsyncStorage. It can only store strings, so storing anything else won't work, like objects etc. Below is how I set and get an array of blocked users.

When you set your item, stringify it:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('blocked_users', JSON.stringify(array));
```

Then when you read it from async storage, use a promise and json parse the data:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("blocked_users")
        .then((value) => {
             if(value){
               blocksArray = JSON.parse(value);
               this.setState({ blocked_users: blocksArray});
             };
        });
```

Comment: This error is not related to AsyncStorage in my code. It only happens randomly in any project I do GraphQL calls. I don't use any third party library for graphQL so it's not something related to Apolo either.

Comment: Right. I'm saying that putting putting the if(value){} in there may help.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if the OP got a solution but I have battled with this error and was able to come up with a solution. The error was originating from AsyncStorage. What I did to solve the issue was to use a conditional statement and set the default value to Null

```
  componentDidMount() {

  AsyncStorage.getItem('Key_0').then((value) => 

this.setState({getValue: value}))
}...
...var avatar 
if(this.state.getValue == null){
avatar = require('path/to/palceholder/asset);
}else if(this.state.getValue ! = null){
avatar={uri: this.state.getValue};
} 

<Image source={avatar}/> //the image source was the root cause of the error since Asyncstorage was passing null value
```

I hope this will help anyone looking for a solution in future.

Answer (score 0):

> my problem was with source of the profile image that i had in my component.

```
source={profileImage && profileImage ? {uri: profileImage} : null}
```

> Check profile image is there and secondly add the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely due to something that wasn't defined in your native IOS code somewhere.

I received this error when I forgot to import a required package for React native IOS notifications in AppDelegate.m